# Cordova: can't add args to window.location for app page

Tags: android, cordova

I'm running cordova 4.3.0. I need pass arguments to another page in the application, but when I add the arguments to the url, the other page does not appear.

I initially used ...

```
url = "edit_metadata.html?audio_path=MyApp/foo.mp4";
console.log("url: " + url);
window.location = url;
```

... which worked as expected in chrome: the new page appeared, and window.location.search contained the args. However, when it ran on android (4.1.1), the console logged the url (including args) correctly, but the new page (edit_metadata.html) did not appear.

When I removed the search string ...

```
url = "edit_metadata.html";
console.log("url: " + url);
window.location = url;
```

... the new page appeared in android, but of course window.location.search was empty.

Is there a way to do the redirect *and* preserve the args in cordova?

Is the addition of the args possibly confusing the whitelist process? My config.xml includes ...

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

... which works for other pages that access sites outside the phone.

Comment: Apparently this is known not to work in cordova. I ended up using
    window.localStorage.setItem("my_item", "my_value);
and
    var my_value = window.localStorage.getItem("my_item");
to pass arguments from one page to another. It's an ugly method because these are essentially globals.